# Add table creation task to Flask-Admin model creation

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm still learning about flask-admin. I have a field called table_name as part of my Department model. When I create a new instance, the value of table_name becomes a row in the Department table. That's what flask-admin is designed to do. I want to actually use the form data i.e. the value of table_name to create a table with sqlalchemy. I know how to create the table dynamically with sqlalchemy. I'm just wondering how to incorporate that into what flask-admin does for me. Example: if I type 'my_table' into the table_name field in the flask admin form, a new table called 'my_table' will be created in my schema.

For example, I have a model defined and one of the fields/columns is 'name'. When I create a new instance of my model in flask-admin, whatever I typed in for 'name' is saved as a row on my table. My question is: what if I actually want to create a whole new table whose name is the string that was supplied to the 'name' attribute? I know I have to use sqlalchemy to dynamically create that table. But where in flask-admin do I add that logic to create the table.

What method or view in flask-admin does the insertion of rows in a table. Maybe I can customize or extend that method and add my code to create tables in addition of the row insertion that flask-admin does. So I want to extend the functionality of flask-admin to do custom stuff for my needs. I've read about the on_model_change and the possibility of overriding it to add custom logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override ModelView's `on_model_change` and `on_model_delete` methods, which are called by flask-admin right before `commit`ing changes:

```
class TableConfig(ModelView):
    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if is_created:
            sqlalchemy_create_table(model)

    def on_model_delete(self, model):
        sqlalchemy_drop)table(model)
```

Where `sqlalchemy_create_table` and `sqlalchemy_drop_table` are custom methods to actually create the tables, using the information in the `model` object that is passed - in your case, the `table_name` property or others.

I actually implemented this exact functionality using flask-admin on a live project.

Comment: Rafael, thanks for your clear and concise answer. I'll comment if I run into any problems ;-) since you've done this exact thing recently.